# Download Manager stops when Internet connection breaks

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Hi In Android my app is downloading big files. I am using in built download Manager. The problem is that the downloads fails when Internet connection breaks. How can I resume downloads? In docs It says that Download Manager retry itself and resume the downloads. But it is not the case. It always fails to download when net connection breaks.